# Enable Statistics (stats) for Scala Tests in Intellij

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, configuration, intellij-13

I want to enable statistics (stats) for Scala Tests in Intellij.

According to this ScalaTest [link](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_shell) there is a way to turn on stats for tests, but the default configuration is nostats (to not show them):

The link suggests running this stats command; is there an equivalent way to run the tests in Intellij?

```
scala> stats.run(new ArithmeticSuite)
```

Here is an example of the sample stats I would like to see:

```
Run completed in 386 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 2
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 1, failed 1, ignored 1, pending 1
```

Perhaps there is a VM parameter or Test option I can set in the configuration?

I am using Intellij 13.4.1 with the Scala Plugin, Scala 2.10, Scalatra 2.3.0, Maven 3.2.3, Java 1.8, Specs2, Windows 7